# Dividing the substring with equal parts on the both side while having three consecutive characters as the divider

Tags: python

Accept a string as input. If the input string is of odd length, then continue with it. If the input string is of even length, make the string of odd length by following the two steps mentioned below:

1. If the last character is a period, then remove it
2. If the last character is not a period, then add a period to the end of the string

Call this string of odd length word. Select a substring made up of three consecutive characters from word such that there are an equal number of characters to the left and right of this substring. Print this substring as output. You can assume that all input strings will be in lower case and will have a length of at least four.

I just tried:

```py
s1 = input() 
s1 = s1.lower()
if (len(s1))%2==0: 
  if s1[-1]==".":
    s1.replace(".","")
  if s1[-1]!=".": 
    s1.join(".") 
word = s1 
print(word)
```

The first part has been solved but for second part I can't seem to have any ideas

Comment: hint: if you have a string of odd length `n`, the middle character of the string is at index `n // 2`

Comment: Show what you have tried so far - otherwise this becomes purely a homework cheating service. 8-)

Comment: s1 = input()
s1 = s1.lower()

if (len(s1))%2==0:
    if s1[-1]==".":
        s1.replace(".","")
    if s1[-1]!=".":
        s1.join(".")
word = s1
print(word)

This is my current code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Once your string has an odd number of characters, the middle position will have an equal number of characters on its left on its right.  So, if you extract the substring starting at the previous character up to the following character, you will meet the criteria  (eg.  `word[len(word)//2:][:3]`)

Comment: @Friedrich sir I have given the code above which is the first half of the problem and I can't seem to get through the second part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add period(`.`) to the end of the string, use `+=` sign.

To get three consecutive characters at the middle of the string, you can do in 2 ways:

1. Use looping: if `s1` is odd, then remove the first character, else remove the last character. Do that until length of `s1` is 3.

```py
while len(s1) > 3:
  if len(s1) % 2 == 0:
    s1 = s1[:-1] 
  else:
    s1 = s1[1:]
```

2. Just slice the string with this formula:

```py
s1[(len(s1) - 3) // 2 : (len(s1) + 3) // 2]
```

---

First way:

```py
s1 = input() 
s1 = s1.lower()
if (len(s1))%2==0: 
  if s1[-1]==".":
    s1.replace(".","")
  else: 
    s1 += '.' 
while len(s1) > 3:
  if len(s1) % 2 == 0:
    s1 = s1[:-1] 
  else:
    s1 = s1[1:] 
word = s1
print(word)
```

---

Second way:

```
s1 = input() 
s1 = s1.lower()
if (len(s1))%2==0: 
  if s1[-1]==".":
    s1.replace(".","")
  else: 
    s1 += '.' 
word = s1[(len(s1) - 3) // 2 : (len(s1) + 3) // 2]  
print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.
That part of code has no issue I want the answer to the second part of the question where string needs to be sliced.

Comment: Can you give me example of the input and the output did you want?

Comment: Test Case 1:
Input: abcdefg
Output: cde
Test Case 2:
Input: abcdefghijk.
Output: efg

Comment: I see. Please take a look at the updated code above.